# Dual boot intermittant issue using Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, grub2, multi-boot

I have a problem with the grub2 loader sometimes. More often, when I choose Windows 7 in the grub2 loader, it hangs on the purple screen. I have looked up and down the internet for an answer and followed every bit of advise. I have of course, downloaded boot-repair in Ubuntu and fixed the grub (3x already!), I edited the conf file to adjust the resolution of the screen, and thirdly, I disabled hibernation option in Windows. Is there something else I am missing? I am fresh out of ideas and resources.

A better question is: What kind of configuration changes or edits can I make on Windows side of things? Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link for a program I can use that will fix the MBR without destroying grub2:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/03/10/restore-the-windows-bootloader-to-mbr-after-dual-booting-with-linux/